# Is it ok if function in perl called without full parameter?

Tags: perl

I have some function in perl like this,

```
sub my_function{
    my ($param1, $param2) = @_;
    #do something here

    if($param1==1){
       #do 1
    }
    if($param2==1){
       #do 2
    }
}
```

is it ok if i call the function without full parameter like this?

```
&my_function($param1);
```

Comment: oh i see, in that case, i will check $param2
for example
if($param2 == 1) like that

Comment: It won't be OK, because you'll get a warning about using an uninitialized value in a comparison. It could be OK if you modify your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass only one argument, `@_`, only contains one value. So `$param2` will be assigned the undefined value. Whether that's okay or not, depends on what the function is doing.

The test below shows one argument, `123` and `(undef)`:

```
sub test {
    my ($x, $y) = @_;
    printf("number of args: %d\n", int @_);
    printf("x: %s\n", $x // "(undef)");
    printf("y: %s\n", $y // "(undef)");
}
test(123);
```

Comment: if i just check $y is undef or not is it will be ok?

Comment: @FerryGideon Yes... `if (defined $param2){...`

Comment: Since `$param2` is boolean here, `if ($param2)` would be more appropriate than `if (defined $param2)`, as I previously mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

`$param2` will end up being `undef`. If that's fine, then yes, it's fine.

In the case you presented, however, it's not fine. `my_function` as written will warn if you don't provide a value for `$param2`. Removing the checks for equality you shouldn't even have in the first place (as follows) fixes that problem.

```
sub my_function {
    my ($param1, $param2) = @_;

    if ($param1) {
       #do 1
    }

    if ($param2){
       #do 2
    }
}
```

Finally, why do you tell Perl to ignore `my_function`'s prototype (by using `&`) when it has no prototype? Get rid of that!

```
my_function($param1);
```

Comment: so its better to define param2 right? oh sorry in my case i ignore the prototype i forgot about it. :D

Comment: Re "*so its better to define param2 right?*", That's nowhere near what I said.